# Aristotle Number Puzzle Explanation

Tags: python, c

P:S: I learned from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/where-to-ask-for-code-explanation) meta thread that code explanations can also be asked on Stack Overflow.

I am trying to understand a solver for the Aristotle Number puzzle from [this](http://hwiechers.blogspot.com/2013/03/solving-artitotles-number-puzzle.html) site. I understood the point till when we do row reduction using Gaussian elimination and found the following:

```
a = 76 - j - k - n - 2o - p - r - s
b = j + n + o
c = -38 + k + o + p + r + s
d = j + k + o
e = -38 + k + n + o + p + r
f = 38 - j - k - n - o - p
g = 38 - k - o - r
h = -38 + n + o + p + r + s
i = 38 - j - k - n - o - r
l = 38 - p - s
m = 38 - n - o - p
q = 38 - r - s
```

The author of the code then continues:

> Now, take each permutation of size 7 from {1, 2, ..., 19}, assign it to the independent variables, generate the dependent ones and test against the constraints until finding solutions.

I am really not understanding this concept. Especially on [this](https://github.com/hwiechers/aristotle_puzzle/blob/master/solver.c) c file, I am not understanding the following two functions:

```
bool next_permutation(void)
{
    for (int x = 6; x >= 0; x--) {
        indices[x]++;

        if (indices[x] == 19) {
            if (!x) {
                return false;
            }
            moveback(x, 18);
            indices[x] = x;
            continue;
        }

        swap(x, indices[x]);
        break;
    }

    j = elem[0];
    k = elem[1];
    n = elem[2];
    o = elem[3];
    p = elem[4];
    r = elem[5];
    s = elem[6];

    return true;
}



// adds values to set
// returns true if value successfully added; false otherwise
bool add(int value)
{
    if (value > 19 || value < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    int bit = 1 << value;
    if (set & bit) {
        return false;
    }

    set |= bit;
    return true;
}
```

I would highly appreciate if someone can help me in understanding this solver. Note the author used python script for row reduction.

Comment: the second function add, uses a bitset to check if the value is already in the set. `bit = 1 << value` encodes the value into a binary set (1 at pos 1, 2 at pos 2, 3 at pos 3 etc.. ). The `set & bit` return true if the value is in the set, in which case the value is not added  (i.e. it's already there -> return false) otherwise, add it to the set (with a OR operation `|=`)

Comment: the other function just shuffle the indices to get a set, rotating over 7 values, swapping and pushing values back when reaching the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is just a method of reducing a set of equations by substituting one equation into the others to eliminate unnecessary variables.  For example you could take the first of the 19 equations and turn it into an equation for a:

```
a = 38 - b - c
```

And then substitute that into the other 18.  This would eliminate a and reduce your equations to 18.  Then repeat until you can't eliminate any more.

It's a nice problem and it gave me an excuse to try out the [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) package.

Here's some code that creates the equations in SymPy and then uses SymPy's `solve` function to reduce the equations.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

# Number of unknowns
n = 19

variable_names = [chr(c + 97) for c in range(19)]

# Create SymPy variables
variables = symbols(variable_names)

print("\n{} unknowns:".format(len(variables)))
print(variables)

# These strings define the equations to be solved
hexagon_rows = [
    'abc',
    'defg',
    'hijkl',
    'mnop',
    'qrs',
    'cgl',
    'bfkp',
    'aejos',
    'dinr',
    'hmq',
    'lps',
    'gkor',
    'cfjnq',
    'beim',
    'adh'
]

def make_expression(chars, rhs=0):
    return parse_expr('+'.join(list(chars)) + '-' + str(rhs))

expressions = []
for chars in hexagon_rows:
    expressions.append(make_expression(chars, 38))

print("\n{} equations to solve:".format(len(expressions)))

for expr in expressions:
    print("{} = 0".format(expr))

# Try to solve the equations
# (They can't be solved but SymPy reduces them down)
reduced_expressions = solve(expressions)

print("\nReduced to {} equations:".format(len(reduced_expressions)))
for var, expr in reduced_expressions.items():
    print("{} = {}".format(var, expr))
```

Output:

```
19 unknowns:
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s]

15 equations to solve:
a + b + c - 38 = 0
d + e + f + g - 38 = 0
h + i + j + k + l - 38 = 0
m + n + o + p - 38 = 0
q + r + s - 38 = 0
c + g + l - 38 = 0
b + f + k + p - 38 = 0
a + e + j + o + s - 38 = 0
d + i + n + r - 38 = 0
h + m + q - 38 = 0
l + p + s - 38 = 0
g + k + o + r - 38 = 0
c + f + j + n + q - 38 = 0
b + e + i + m - 38 = 0
a + d + h - 38 = 0

Reduced to 12 equations:
j = b - n - o
k = e - n - o - p - r + 38
l = -p - s + 38
i = -b - e + n + o + p
c = e - n + s
f = -b - e + n + o + r
g = -e + n + p
q = -r - s + 38
m = -n - o - p + 38
h = n + o + p + r + s - 38
d = b + e - 2*n - o - p - r + 38
a = -b - e + n - s + 38
```

Hope that helps.  With the first part at least!